# Prevent ColorTransform from changing other filter colors (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, filter, colors, transform

I am trying to change the color of a movieclip when clicked, however I have a shadow filter on it that I want to stay black.

```
var cty:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
cty.color = 0xFFFF00; //color transform yellow
var shdw:DropShadowFilter = new DropShadowFilter(); 
shdw.color = 0x000000; <----clearly set to black
shdw.distance = 3; 
shdw.angle = 45;
shdw.strength = 1;
shdw.blurX = 3; 
shdw.blurY = 3;
thisclip.filters=[shdw];

thisclip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,myevent);
function myevent(e:MouseEvent):void
{
thisclip.transform.colorTransform = cty;
thisclip.filters=[shdw];  <------ tried adding a refresher but doesnt work
}
```

The problem is that after the color change the shadow is changed to the same color as the object, is there a way to change the color WITHOUT changing the shadow filter color???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that after the color change the shadow is changed to
>   the same color as the object, is there a way to change the color
>   WITHOUT changing the shadow filter color???

**You need to separate the item you want to be drop-shadowed and the item you want to colour transformed**. One way is to create a "container" for `thisclip` and apply the shadow to the container itself, then only transform the colour of `this clip`. I've modified your code to show what I mean...

```
var cty:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
cty.color = 0xFFFF00; //# yellow

var shdw:DropShadowFilter = new DropShadowFilter(); 
shdw.color = 0x000000; //# black 
shdw.strength = 1;
shdw.distance = 3; shdw.angle = 45; 
shdw.blurX = shdw.blurY = 3; //# linked since same value for both

var contMC : MovieClip = new MovieClip;
addChild( contMC ); //# add to stage
contMC.addChild( thisclip ); //# add "thisclip" into container MC
contMC.x = 0; contMC.y = 0; //# set your own position

//thisclip.filters=[shdw];
contMC.filters=[shdw];

thisclip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myevent);

function myevent(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    thisclip.transform.colorTransform = cty;
    //e.currentTarget.transform.colorTransform = cty; //# use this for ANY listening object

}
```

Just remember if you create the container MC by code (like I showed) you can reference any added children by their usual instance names like so : `thisclip.transform.colorTransform = cty;`

But if you create the container MC on stage (with instance name `contMC` and cut/paste `thisclip` MC into it, then you now reference it by code as : `contMC.thisclip.transform.colorTransform = cty;`

**tip #1 :** To avoid adding a container, if your `thisclip` itself has an MC (or Sprite) holding some "to be coloured" content you can instead target that content by its instance name : 
`thisclip.someContent.transform.colorTransform = cty;`
(here `thisclip` becomes the container with shadow, whilst `someContent` is the inner MC to be colour transformed).

**tip #2 :** I've added the line `e.currentTarget.transform.colorTransform = cty;` (but is commented out since not used) to show how you could have any clicked MC respond to the colour transform. Just make sure they are listening to the event like so : 
`clipInstanceName.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myevent);` 
(now you can have multiple **IF** checks and adjust colour accordingly per clicked item using `cty.color = some new Value;` within `if` statements, before finally setting that `.colorTransform = cty;` ...